# Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment on page refresh when the page refreshes

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I have an Angular 8 app that loads devices from a SQLite Database and displays them all in a url named "monitoring". When i want the user to view details about a current devices he gets redirected to " "monitoring/:id" all works fine! However if the user refreshes the url "monitoring/:id" the selected device is null and i get the following error "Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '123'". This the Route module for root

app.module.ts

```
RouterModule.forRoot([

  { path: '', redirectTo: '/monitoring', pathMatch: 'full' }, 
  { path: 'monitoring', component: AppMonitoring, pathMatch: 'full', data: { state: 'monitor' }, },
  { path: "monitoring/:id", component: DeviceMeasurements,  },
  { path: 'management', component: AppManagement, pathMatch: 'full', data: { state: 'manage' } },
  { path: 'system', component: AppSystemSettings, pathMatch: 'full', data: { state: 'system' }, },
  { path: 'notifications', component: AppSettingsNotifications, pathMatch: 'full', data: { state: 'notifications' }, },

], { useHash: true }
)],
```

Please tell me if any more information is needed and how can this issue be resoved?
Thank you for your time!

Edit : this is the HTML that redirects the url

```
<a class="pull-left" href="#" (click)="DeviceDelete()" onclick="return false;" matTooltip="{{language_service.getText(this.language_service.ITEMS.DEVICE_DELETE)}}">         <i class="nav-icon fa fa-trash"></i>   </a>
```

Content of  ViewMeasurements

```
  ViewMeasurements() {
    this.device_service.SetCurrentDevice(this.device);
    this.router.navigateByUrl(`/monitoring/${this.device.id}`);
  }
```

Content of SetCurrentDevice

```
  SetCurrentDevice(device: DeviceInterface) {
    this.InitCurrentDevice.next(device);
  }
```

I also have a GetCurrentDevice function which is called in the dynamic id page

```
  GetCurrentDevice(): DeviceInterface  {
    return this.InitCurrentDevice.getValue();
  }
```

and use it like this in the dynamic page

```
  ngOnInit() {
      this.device = this.device_service.GetCurrentDevice(); 
  }
```

I have tried the following in the ngOnInit function but it resulted the same error

```
    let n = window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/');
    let id = window.location.href.substring(n + 1);
    if(this.device==null){
        this._router.navigateByUrl('/monitoring', { skipLocationChange: true }).then(() => {
    
          this._router.navigate(['/monitoring/' + id]);
        });

}
```

Comment: How are you getting the device id initially? Once the application is refreshed, it looses any data that was loaded previously.

Comment: you can check inside DeviceMeasurements if there is an id and no data that you can redirect it to the monitoring route

Comment: On the deviceID page i do not want to redirect also i have added more detailed explanation how the CurrentDevice is being set / get. Also what have i tried to prevent it

Answer (score 1):

Put this path `{ path: '', redirectTo: '/monitoring', pathMatch: 'full' }` at the bottom of your path object.

Comment: This partly fixed the issue, the page loads but the error " Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '123' " is still there.

Comment: Can you remove the forward-slash (/) in  *this._router.navigate(['/monitoring/' + id]);*

Comment: It does not working without the forward-slash, the following error is shown - " Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'monitoring123'"

Comment: Hello, creating route such as " management:id " everything worked as expected so this answer helped me solve the issue